# error r: invalid subscript type "closure" in a simple regression

Tags: r

unfortunately i am a beginner in r. I d like to run a simple linear regression model in r with the comand lm, but every time i try the following error occurs:

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'

The regression model ist just as follows:

```
REG1 <- lm(flowpercent~ret+tna+fundage+number_shr_cl,data = reg, na.omit)
 #-flowpercent is a calculated variable:

reg$flowpercent <- reg$flow_dollar/lag(reg$tna, n=1)

 #-fundage is also calculated:

reg$fundage <- as.numeric(difftime(ref_date,reg$InceptionDate, units = "days")/365.25)
```

`ret`, tna`,` `number_shr_cl` are variables from a database

hopefully some can help me to solve my problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what's in `reg` ?

Comment: reg is the name of the data.frame.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mcve] and [ask] so as to create questions that the helpful people here can easily answer. Luckily, in your case, I can guess what has happened and have answered it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your third argument is `na.omit`. You probably saw someone writing something like `na.action = na.omit`. However, if you look up the help for `lm` by typing `?lm`, you will see:

```
Usage:

     lm(formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, ... # etc
```

which tells you that the third argument to `lm` is `subset`. So, you are passing the object called `na.omit` to the `subset` argument, which `lm` tries to use to subset your data.  Unfortunately, `na.omit` is an R function (aka a "closure"). Not surprisingly, R does not know how to use this function to subset your data. Hence the error.